# Parse JSON array in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I'm trying to parse the following json array

```
[
    {
        "email": "john.doe@sendgrid.com",
        "timestamp": 1337197600,
        "smtp-id": "<4FB4041F.6080505@sendgrid.com>",
        "event": "processed"
    },
    {
        "email": "john.doe@sendgrid.com",
        "timestamp": 1337966815,
        "smtp-id": "<4FBFC0DD.5040601@sendgrid.com>",
        "category": "newuser",
        "event": "clicked"
    },
    {
        "email": "john.doe@sendgrid.com",
        "timestamp": 1337969592,
        "smtp-id": "<20120525181309.C1A9B40405B3@Example-Mac.local>",
        "event": "processed"
    }
]
```

I've not really used json format before, so it's all a little new. I found I can parse a single element easily, i.e.

```
{
        "email": "john.doe@sendgrid.com",
        "timestamp": 1337197600,
        "smtp-id": "<4FB4041F.6080505@sendgrid.com>",
        "event": "processed"
}

dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
Response.Write(string.Format("{0} = {1}<br />", "timestamp", stuff.timestamp)); 
//etc
```

But i'm struggling with how to get the individual elements into an array to loop through.

I though about splitting the sting on },{ but didn't have much luck with that. I imagine there's an easier way i'm missing.

Thank you.

Comment: *stuff* is an array. Use `stuff[i].timestamp`

Answer (score 7):

Just deserialize the JSON as is and loop it...

```
dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

foreach (var s in stuff) 
{
     Console.WriteLine(s.timestamp);
}
```

Fiddle: http://dotnetfiddle.net/0SthDp

Answer (score 7):

You can create a class like this one, to accept all properties from the json string:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string email { get; set; }

    public long timestamp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("smtp-id")]
    public string smtpid { get; set; }

    public string category { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("event")]
    public string evt { get; set; }
}
```

As you can notice there is `JsonProperty` attribute on the `smtpid` and `evt` properties, because you can not use the names in the `json` string as properties in `C#`.

Then just call the following line:

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(json);
```

and you'll get a strongly typed list of objects that matches the json string.

Answer (score 1):

Create these two classes to hold your data:

```
public class SMTPEvent {
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public long TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public string SmtpId { get; set; }
    public string EventType { get; set; }
}

public class SMTPEvents {
    public List<SMTPEvent> Events { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can call the following:

```
dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SMTPEvents>(json);
```

To iterate you can then use:

```
foreach(SMTPEvent sEvent in stuff)
{
    //whatever you want to do.
}
```

The advantage to this approach is having more type safety at run-time whilst having reusable objects if you're going to use them in other parts of your system. If not, you might want to use the simpler `dynamic` approach as suggested by others.

Also, remember to use the JsonProperty attribute to specify the actual property name as specified in your JSON string if you cannot / are not going to create fields that have the exact name as in your JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The first level - `stuff` - is an *Array* of objects. It is the objects, or elements in said array, which contain a `timestamp` field.

Consider the following:

```
dynamic items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
foreach(dynamic item in items) {
   /* use item.timestamp */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json) to do this for you:

Create a class to hold the data (notice the attribute I put on smtp-id to handle characters C# doesn't like):

```
public class EmailEvent
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int TimeStamp { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName="smtp-id")]
    public string SmtpId { get; set; }
    public string Event { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

Then just deserialize it:

```
var events = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EmailEvent>>(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"z:\temp\test.json"));

foreach (var ev in events)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ev.SmtpId);
}
```