# How do I deserialize a json with nested array in c# using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. I ma trying to create a console weather app. I have fetched JSON data from OpenWeather API which looks like this:

```
  "coord": {
    "lon": 27.5667,
    "lat": 53.9
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 800,
      "main": "Clear",
      "description": "clear sky",
      "icon": "01d"
    }
  ],
```

I have called `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherInfo>(stringResult);`

I am able to deserialize the `coord` part, however the `weather` part is an array, how do I deserialize it?

````
private class WeatherInfo
        {
            public Coord Coord { get; set; }

            public Weather Weather { get; set; }
        }

        private class Weather
        {
            public readonly string Id;
            public readonly string Main;
            public readonly string Description;
            public readonly string Icon;

            public Weather(string lat, string lon, string id, string main, string description, string icon)
            {
                Id = id;
                Main = main;
                Description = description;
                Icon = icon;
            }
        }
        
        private class Coord
        {
            public readonly string Lat;
            public readonly string Lon;

            public Coord(string lat, string lon)
            {
                Lat = lat;
                Lon = lon;
            }
        }
        ```
````

Comment: `public Weather[] Weather { get; set; }`?

Comment: @gunr2171 I looked, but feel free.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse JSON array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21974019/parse-json-array-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Fildor got it right. If your JSON property is an array, you need to treat your c# property as a collection (array, list, IEnumerable, ICollection, etc).

Comment: I don't think the dupe is really good. For one, it doesn't have an accepted answer. And second, it's about a "first-class" array, not an array property...

Comment: @Fildor How would I then print it? 
`Console.WriteLine(weatherInfo.Weather.Main);`
gives me `cannot resolve symbol 'Main'`

Comment: @user434002 It's not really that. To a newbie it may seems as so, but "the elders" are really only doing houskeeping. SO seeks to be helpful. So if you are searching for a solution for a problem, you'd probably not want to have to go through 156 times the same question with the same answer. Sometimes - and especially for newbies - it's not so easy to know you are writing a duplicate question. And sometimes opinions differ over whether something is a dupe or not. We're all human. We make mistakes.

Comment: @Fildor understand. I just had an account shut down because my questions weren't good enough. It can be very frustrating on a newbie who is already overwhelmed by the programming langauge, you know?

Comment: `How would I then print it?` - `weatherInfo.Weather` is now an array. You'll have to iterate it.

Comment: ^^ e.g. `foreach( var weather in weatherInfo.Weather ) { Console.WriteLine(weather.Main); }`

Comment: @Fildor Thanks, you are awesome. And thanks for clearing that all up man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `public Weather[] Weather { get; set; }` to map.The C# Object Equivalent of your JSON will be like this

```
public partial class Temperatures
{
    [JsonProperty("coord")]
    public Coord Coord { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("weather")]
    public Weather[] Weather { get; set; }
}

public partial class Coord
{
    [JsonProperty("lon")]
    public double Lon { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lat")]
    public double Lat { get; set; }
}

public partial class Weather
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("main")]
    public string Main { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("icon")]
    public string Icon { get; set; }
}
```